# Highcharts title animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm trying to apply [Circulate framework effects](http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/) on highcharts `title`. Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function () {
    $(".highcharts-title text").each(function() {
        $(this).circulate({
            speed: Math.floor(Math.random()*300) + 100,
            height: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470,
            width: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: what is your issue exactly?

Comment: @web-tiki I don't find how to apply the effect only on the charts titles since they are generated automatically with Highcharts Javascript!

Comment: I think you'll likely run into problems since the title is inside an SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set it to be rendered as HTML.
Just add **[useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.useHTML)** property in your code:

```
title: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: 'Marketers, on average, spend over a quarter of their marketing budget on content marketing.'
    },
```

Then you can apply animation:

```
$("span.highcharts-title").circulate({
                speed: Math.floor(Math.random()*300) + 100,
                height: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470,
                width: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470
            })
```